# How can I get ViewScope value stored as an object in Java?

Tags: jsf, xpages

I have an object stored in the ViewScope: ObjectName (valueA:one, valueB:two)

[image]

I stored the values using Java:

```
ObjectObject location = new ObjectObject();
location.put("valueA", FBSUtility.wrap("one"));
location.put("valueB", FBSUtility.wrap("two"));
Utils.setViewScope("ObjectName", location);
```

How would I go about retrieving these values from the ViewScope? I've tried doing something like the following:

```
ObjectObject location;
location = (ObjectObject) ExtLibUtil.getViewScope().get("ObjectName");
```

but I'm not sure what methods to use to get the values or if this is even the correct path. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit unusual to go out of your way to use the FBS classes, but that path is reasonable enough to accomplish what you want. As long as the latter code is executed after the format, that should retrieve the same object and properly cast it to `ObjectObject`. After that, you could use `location.get("valueA")`, etc. to get the values by name, and then whatever methods of `FBSValue` are appropriate (I'd guess `stringValue()`).

Incidentally, unless you have a specific need to use these internal classes (like if you're doing something fancy with SSJS functions), it may make sense to use just a normal `HashMap<String, Object>` instead. SSJS and EL can work with those quite well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was only using the FBS classes because I came across a post (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9919089/1193140) that showed how to set an object to a scope. Do you know of an example that shows how to use a HashMap to do something similar?

Comment: Something like this would do it:

    `Map<String, Object> location = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    location.put("valueA", "one");
    location.put("valueB", "two");
    ExtLibUtil.getViewScope().put("ObjectName", location);`  followed by `Map<String, Object> location = (Map<String, Object>)ExtLibUtil.getViewScope().get("ObjectName");` later.